# Is it possible to import Groovy into settings.gradle without having Groovy locally installed?

Tags: gradle, groovy

I have a settings.gradle in my project root as:

```
rootProject.name = 'root'                                                       
                                                                                
new File('.').eachFileRecurse FileType.FILES,  { file ->                        
                                                                                                        
    if (file.name.matches("build.gradle")) {                                    
        println "Dir name ${file.getParentFile().getName()}"             
    }                                                                           
}
```

Script is used to list all directory names (last child) where `build.gradle` is found.
However this script doesn't work without an `import groovy.io.FileType`.

Any ideas to have that Groovy import included, without having it locally installed, into `settings.gradle` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bro, Groovy is a part of Gradle by default, put that `import` statement back where it should be and everything is good, no worries.

If you don't trust me, delete your locally installed Groovy and check it out :)